# Android animate LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I have a layout like in the picture. A LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout.

I am new to android, I would likes to animate in LinearLayout from right to left on a button click or any.

Can any one please show me a tutorial or code sample for the same ?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) and use the same code, for whatever transition you want for the linear layout. (The linear layout will become the view that you wish to animate)

Hope the clue suffices!